# How do I apply multiple profiles at once on Gentoo?

Tags: gentoo, emerge

I am installing KDE on a Gentoo Linux Hardened system. The official Gentoo wiki says the recommended way is to apply the KDE desktop profile, issue `emerge -NDu --with-bdeps=y @world`, and then install the `kdebase-meta` package. However, I am on the Hardened profile and apparently I can only have one selected profile at once.

So far I've been successful with manually applying the KDE profile's global and per-package USE flags on my Portage configuration files (/etc/portage/make.conf, /etc/portage/package.use and stuff), but I fear this hack might be rather difficult to maintain in the long run as the Gentoo dev team modifies the profile. Every time I get a Portage update, I'd have to reapply the `desktop` and `desktop/kde` profiles' USE flags and configuration just in case they were changed.

Is there any other way to have multiple active Portage profiles at once on Gentoo Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Problem

As you have discovered, Gentoo only allows one Profile Setup at a time.  As you can see from my `eselect profile list`:

```
 [1]   default/linux/amd64/13.0
 [2]   default/linux/amd64/13.0/selinux
 [3]   default/linux/amd64/13.0/desktop
 [4]   default/linux/amd64/13.0/desktop/gnome
 [5]   default/linux/amd64/13.0/desktop/gnome/systemd
 [6]   default/linux/amd64/13.0/desktop/kde *
 [7]   default/linux/amd64/13.0/desktop/kde/systemd
 [8]   default/linux/amd64/13.0/desktop/plasma
 [9]   default/linux/amd64/13.0/desktop/plasma/systemd
 [10]  default/linux/amd64/13.0/developer
 [11]  default/linux/amd64/13.0/no-multilib
 [12]  default/linux/amd64/13.0/systemd
 [13]  default/linux/amd64/13.0/x32
 [14]  hardened/linux/amd64
 [15]  hardened/linux/amd64/selinux
 [16]  hardened/linux/amd64/no-multilib
 [17]  hardened/linux/amd64/no-multilib/selinux
 [18]  hardened/linux/amd64/x32
 [19]  hardened/linux/musl/amd64
 [20]  hardened/linux/musl/amd64/x32
 [21]  default/linux/uclibc/amd64
 [22]  hardened/linux/uclibc/amd64
```

### Solution

Having set your profile to hardened (14 on my list), we now need to examine the files for the KDE Profile: (note that this takes a bit of writing without a text editor):

1. `cd /usr/portage/profiles/targets/desktop/kde`
2. `nano -w make.defaults`
3. `nano -w parent`
4. You should now see files in `/usr/portage/profiles/targets/desktop/`.
5. `nano -w make.defaults`

Using Scratch Paper, copy down the USE Flags from Step 2, and opening `parent` in Step 3 reveals `..` , which now means we travel one directory up.  Copy the USE Flags from Step 5.  As the final step, issue `emerge -v app-portage/ufed && ufed`. You can now set the USE Flags you copied down in `/etc/portage/make.conf`.  You may want to repeat the process for:

- `/usr/portage/profiles/desktop/kde/package.use`
- `/usr/portage/profiles/desktop/package.use`

by placing the packages listed in those two files into `/etc/portage/package.use`.

---

During Syncs, files in `/etc/portage` will not be overwritten and the USE Flags in `/etc/portage/make.conf` will mimic the behavior you are trying to achieve. See the [Portage Files Section in the Handbook](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Portage/Files) for more information.  In essence, your Portage overrides in `/etc/portage` will add to your hardened profile, as Portage uses your configuration before it reads your selected profile. I know it's a pain as the USE Flags in the profiles `package.use` files can be updated with each sync, so you will need to see if any are added after each sync.  Generally, the profile files aren't updated very often.

Answer (score 4):

## Use cascading

Profiles allow for [cascading](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Profile_(Portage)#Structure), no need to manually set useflags:

> All profiles are cascading/stackable profiles composed by several
>   subprofiles...

The same page also contains a chapter specifically for answering for the demand in this questions:

> ### [Combining profiles](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Profile_(Portage)#Combining_profiles)
>
> If there isn't a profile in the Gentoo repository that meets your
>   exact requirements, you can try combining multiple profiles into a
>   single custom profile. An example of this would be combining a
>   hardened profile with a desktop systemd profile, such as
>   default/linux/amd64/17.0/desktop/plasma/systemd and
>   default/linux/amd64/17.0/hardened. It is expected that you already
>   have a custom repository set up.

The wikipage leads you to more links how to set up a repository and finally create the profile.

### HowTo

Here is a summary on how I've done it for a `no-multilib/plasma/systemd`combination (adjust to your needs):

#### 1. Create directory structure for repository

```
mkdir -p /usr/portage/local/{metadata,profiles/default/linux/amd64/17.0/no-multilib/plasma/systemd}
```

#### 2. Define the parents

Edit `/usr/portage/local/profiles/default/linux/amd64/17.0/no-multilib/plasma/systemd/parent` to contain something like:

```
/usr/portage/profiles/default/linux/amd64/17.0/desktop/plasma/systemd
/usr/portage/profiles/default/linux/amd64/17.0/no-multilib
```

Note that the documentation uses relative paths, but I found the level of negative recursions (`../../..`) a wee bit confusing. Absolute paths work just as fine, unless you plan on moving `/usr/portage` around on the system.

I found that a lower line takes preference. So if a flag or setting is set / unset in the first profile, and the opposite happens in a lower line, the lower line's profile setting applies. For instance, `plasma` profile allows for some `multi-lib` settings. If I where to set the *multi-lib* line above the *plasma* one, some packages will still be attempted to be build as *multi-lib* (giving all sorts of funny build failures). You may need to play around with the order of this lines.

#### 3. Set repository metadata

Edit `/usr/portage/local/metadata/layout.conf`. Auto-sync tells `emerge --sync` not to sync this repository.

```
masters = gentoo
auto-sync = false
```

Define the friendly name. This will be prefixed to all the `eselect profile list` entries for this repo. `/usr/portage/local/profiles/repo_name`:

```
local
```

And `/usr/portage/local/profiles/profiles.desc` will tell `eselect` where to look for profiles. First field is *arch*, second profile name, and third field *stable* or *experimental*:

```
amd64 default/linux/amd64/17.0/no-multilib/plasma/systemd stable
```

#### 4. Make portage aware of this new repository

Create and edit `/etc/portage/repos.conf/local.conf` to contain:

```
[local]
location = /usr/portage/local
```

#### 5. Set the profile and fingers crossed

```
~# eselect profile list
[...]
[55]  local:default/linux/amd64/17.0/no-multilib/plasma/systemd (stable)
~# eselect profile set 55
~# emerge --update --newuse --deep --ask --verbose @world
```

### Maintenance friendly

Although, this is a bit of work to set up, it is very easy to maintain. Profile useflags and setting always keep in sync with the main tree. Even if once in a while it is necessary to update the profile version, it goes without too may difficulty. For instance, if there is a new profile version from the Gentoo tree:

```
~# cd /usr/portage/local/profiles/default/linux/amd64
~# cp -av 17.0 18.0
~# vi 18.0/no-multilib/plasma/systemd/parent
/usr/portage/profiles/default/linux/amd64/18.0/desktop/plasma/systemd
/usr/portage/profiles/default/linux/amd64/18.0/no-multilib
~# vi /usr/portage/local/profiles/profiles.desc
amd64 default/linux/amd64/18.0/no-multilib/plasma/systemd stable
~# eselect [...]
```